# using observer pattern to model notifications to subscribers

Tags: python, design-patterns, observer-pattern

This might be a little long question but i try to keep it as small as possible and try to put it in the best way i can.

I have reading about design patterns and found observer pattern very intresting. i searched for its practical application and found various answers [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-real-world-uses-of-observer-pattern). one of those answer was:

> Whenever a question is posted, all the subscribers following the topics of similar interest are notified.

i tried to model this system in python as below:

using [Mongoengine ORM](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html) to model a **User** and define a function ***notify*** for the User class which can be used to notify a user:

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('tumblelog')


# User model
class User(Document):
        email = StringField()
        first_name = StringField()
        last_name = StringField()
        topic_subscribed = StringField()

        def notify(self):
                print "email sent to user :{} {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)
                print "user was subsacribed to: {}".format(self.topic_subscribed)






# simulate publishing of an article of a particular topic
while True:
        x = raw_input(">>>")
        print "question of {} topic published".format(x)

        # How to notify all users that are subscribed to the topic ?????
        # naive way :
        # def some_aynchronous_function():
        #       1) find all users from db that are subscribed to the topic
        #       2) notify each user by looping through all of them
```

I know the trivial way it can be done but can I do something better by using observer pattern here?

**NOTE**: I am not trying to fit the problem to the design pattern as it is usually frowned upon. I am just trying to implement it for ***learning purpose**. I have tried searching for some implementations but unsuccessful so far

**MY QUESTION** : I presented the way I know I could have approached the problem(pseudocode above) but is there anything that can be done better using an observer pattern here?

Answer (score 0):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods.

source: [Wikipedia - Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Your `Observer` is your `User` but you still need to define your `Subject` which in your case would probably be called `Topic`. This topic would keep a list of all its `subscribers` in an internal list. Then when an update occurs the topic would notify all it's subscribers by looping through each one and calling some method of theirs. For example:

```
class Topic:
    subscribers = []

    def addSubscriber(self, subscriber):
        subscribers.append(subscriber)

    def notifySubscribers(self):
        for subscriber : subscribers:
            subscriber.notify(self)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i can atleast see a bigger picture of how things would stick together, however, i have a small doubt .For any middle to large size aplication or a popular web service we might have lot of users say.500,000 as an example. now would it make sense to keep all theses users internally in a list in memory at all the times?what happens when new users are added to the database?

Comment: You're right, keeping them in memory would most likely be implausible. In that case you could instead keep a reference of their id's and only load them into memory when the topic needs to notify subscribers. Some `persistence` frameworks can handle this for you by `Lazy Loading` the objects into memory when called. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading